# FWHM and Beam Width of transmitted beam of ultrasonic (ultrasound) transducer

Tags: waves, acoustics, signal-processing

Im a studying ultrasonic transducer and I got a question about FWHM and Beam Width while solving some problems.

In the lecture, I learned that Beam width is calculated by:

$2\Delta\theta = \frac{3.8\lambda}{\pi L}$

where $\lambda$ is wavelength defined by $c/f$ and $L$ is a diameter of the transducer.

However, Im confused with FWHM. I thought that FWHM and Beam width are the same. But, Following the formula dose not compute right values.

I cannot find any explanations about relationship between FWHM and Beamwidth.

Some words like -3dB width, angular resolution are seen, but I couldn't get any clear result.